# Return a figure directly from callback in Dash

Tags: python, callback, plotly, figure, plotly-dash

I have a function that returns a figure directly and I want that figure to be placed in layout's Div. The fact is that as far as I know, is not posible to return this type of object in a callback

I do not know how to solve this problem to return the figure. Next, I would have to modify that figure too.

The function that returns the figure:

```
   fig=plt.figure() #set up the figures
   fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
   ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
   draw_pitch(ax) # Here I draw some lines over the figure
   ax.plot()
   return fig
```

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from utils import p_number, plot_pitch
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Input(id='my-id', value=p_number(7), type='text'),
   html.Div(id='my-div')

])


@app.callback(
   Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
   [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')],
   [State('local', 'data')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return plot_pitch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dash supports figures generated with `plotly` but not `matplotlib` as you appear to have done here... Here is the related documentation: https://dash.plot.ly/interactive-graphing